# How to redirect based on string match in url

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect based on whether the url contains a string review?review

For example
https://www.example.com/reviews/the-good-diet.1306/review?review=1730#review-1730
should redirect to 
https://www.example.com/reviews/the-good-diet.1306/

Another example
https://www.example.com/reviews/the-bad-diet.1417/review?review=1936#review-1936
should redirect to 
https://www.example.com/reviews/the-bad-diet.1417/

Can anyone help please

Answer (score 0):

Check this rule on top of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^reviews\/(.*)\/review(.*)$ /reviews/$1/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you. that redirected with the "#review-1730" appended to the end, but good enough :)